# Handle Dynamic Div Click Event Using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How can i know which div click event has been triggered using Jquery Here is the fiddler link [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rickjackson/6ghXz/4/). Actually I am dynamically generating the div in my placeholder I dont know how can i know which div has been clicked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get this by checking this like

```
$(".nailthumb-container").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id")); 
    //alert(this.id); //you can also try this
    alert('Hii');
});
```

and if you want to get who trigger this event, you can get the target like, here place e, which will capture the event object.

```
$(".nailthumb-container").click(function (e) {
    alert(e.target.id);
    alert('Hii');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

well you can simple do it using `this`

`this` will give you object of div on which you have clicked

```
$(".nailthumb-container").click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ghXz/5/)